# OpenShift BuildConfig Docker strategy spec.output.to.name using environment variable for tagging

Tags: docker, environment-variables, jenkins-pipeline, openshift, buildconfig

I have defined the following OpenShift BuildConfig:

```
<snip>
    output:
      to:
        kind: DockerImage
        name: myregistry.com/myapp:${TAG}
    strategy:
      type: Docker
      dockerStrategy:
        from:
          kind: ImageStreamTag
          name: nodejs-12:latest
          namespace: myproject
        env:
          - name: TAG
            value: latest
```

I would like the TAG to be a version number which consists of version from the application `package.json` and the Jenkins `#build` number. So I plan to pass this env value in the OpenShift `start-build` command line using the `-e` option. However, when applying the BuildConfig definition, it complains that `name is not a valid Docker pull specification: invalid reference format`. How do I use variable to specify image tag string value? Any advice and insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, this is not possible using a single `BuildConfig`. The `output` part is evaluated during object creation, your build container environment can't set that tag later on.

You may want to use a `Template` instead, creating `BuildConfigs` for earch tag you need to build.

Or, assuming OpenShift 4+, you could look into `Tekton`. The `Pipeline` object allows for generic build definitions - though still requires creating `PipelineResources` for each image tag, as well as git source ref.

Comment: I can not belevive this is not possible by design